# Backbone.js: avoid view→model→view double conversion

Tags: model-view-controller, data-binding, backbone.js, model-binding

I’m trying to build [this:

[image]](http://jsbin.com/asokok/2/edit)

When I edit field on the left it should update the one on the right and vice-versa.

- Editing a value in an input field causes the text cursor to jump at the end of it.
- Typing "2" in the fahrenheit field gets replaced with 1.999999999999, as you can see on the screenshot. This happens because of the double conversion:
  **view’s Fº → model’s Cº → view’s Fº.**

[image: recoil]

How can I avoid that?

---

**Update:**

I want to know the elegant way of dealing with two-way bindings in MVC frameworks such as Backbone.js.

## MVC

```
var Temperature = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        celsius: 0
    },
    fahrenheit: function(value) {
        if (typeof value == 'undefined') {
            return this.c2f(this.get('celsius'));
        }
        value = parseFloat(value);
        this.set('celsius', this.f2c(value));
    },
    c2f: function(c) {
        return 9/5 * c + 32;
    },
    f2c: function(f) {
        return 5/9 * (f - 32);
    }
});


var TemperatureView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: document.body,
    model: new Temperature(),
    events: {
        "input #celsius": "updateCelsius",
        "input #fahrenheit": "updateFahrenheit"
    },
    initialize: function() {
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'change:celsius', this.render);
        this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
        this.$('#celsius').val(this.model.get('celsius'));
        this.$('#fahrenheit').val(this.model.fahrenheit());
    },
    updateCelsius: function(event) {
        this.model.set('celsius', event.target.value);
    },
    updateFahrenheit: function(event) {
        this.model.fahrenheit(event.target.value);
    }
});

var temperatureView = new TemperatureView();
```

## No MVC

```
celsius.oninput = function(e) {
    fahrenheit.value = c2f(e.target.value)
}
fahrenheit.oninput = function(e) {
    celsius.value = f2c(e.target.value)
}
function c2f(c) {
    return 9/5 * parseFloat(c) + 32;
}
function f2c(f) {
    return 5/9 * (f - 32);
}
```

Not only it fixes the problem, it’s also reduces the code 3.5⨉. Clearly I’m doing MVC wrong.

Comment: I generally multiply by whatever factor of 10 is necessary to make non-fractional integers, do the math, then divide by the factor of 10 when I'm done to avoid the grossness of javascript decimal math.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's my take on this; instead rendering the whole view on every change, in interactive views, use the view's jQuery or plain JS contexts just like your non-MVC example.

http://jsbin.com/fomugixe/1/edit

As the Backbone docs say:

> "Two way data-binding" is avoided. While it certainly makes for a nifty demo, and works for the most basic CRUD, it doesn't tend to be terribly useful in your real-world app. Sometimes you want to update on every keypress, sometimes on blur, sometimes when the panel is closed, and sometimes when the "save" button is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Two methods come to mind. As Kinakuta mentioned you can do something like the following so you're math works on integers, instead of decimals:

```
temp = ((oldTemp * 100) * conversion stuff) / 100
```

Depending on how complex you want your app to be you can also use something like [`Backbone.ModelBinder`](https://github.com/theironcook/Backbone.ModelBinder). It automatically binds your view to your model so when one updates, the other updates automatically. You can then attach a converter function to the binding so when your value goes `view -> model` or `model -> view` it's run through the converter. I can elaborate more if that idea interests you.

**Update**: With a simple temp converter it's not surprising that Backbone requires 3.5x as much code. An MVC framework can reduce bloat in a large project, but for a small app it might be overkill. e.g. imagine using Backbone to display "Hello World".

As for your issue, how about only rendering the *other* input value when one is changed, instead of both? If F input changes, re-render value in C box. With `ModelBinder` I would do this by having two attributes in my model: `tempF` and `tempC`. When one is modified, I re-calculate the other and ModelBinder automatically displays it. Or you can go without MB and just listen for the change event.

Comment: Rounding is just a hack. I’d like to know how to avoid an unnecessary re-rendering. Please do elaborate more.

Comment: @NVI See my update. Your main issue is you shouldn't re-render the input field that the user changed, just re-render the other one.

Answer (score 0):

set a variable at the view level where you hold the input field that started the conversion, so you don't call the conversion function on that field.