# React.js: Avoid updates of currently edited input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image: Double-conversion problem]

Demo: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NV/qQ5Cs/)

```
/**
 * @jsx React.DOM
 */
var NumberField = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <input type="number" value={this.props.value} onInput={this.onInput}/>;
    },
    onInput: function(e) {
        if (!this.props.onValueChange) {
            return;
        }
        var value = parseInt(e.target.value, 10);
        return this.props.onValueChange(value);
    }
});

var TempConverter = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {c: 0};
    },
    render: function() {
        var c = this.state.c;
        return <p>
            <NumberField onValueChange={this.onChangeC} value={c}/> C
            <br/>
            <NumberField onValueChange={this.onChangeF} value={c2f(c)}/> F
        </p>;
    },
    onChangeC: function(c) {
        this.setState({c: c});
    },
    onChangeF: function(f) {
        this.setState({c: f2c(f)});
    }
});


function c2f(c) {
    return 1.8 * c + 32;
}
function f2c(f) {
    return 0.5555555555555 * (f - 32);
}
```

When I change the °F value by one, it gets converted to Celsius and then back to Fahrenheit, resulting in rounding errors.

Is there any way to avoid updates on the currently modified element?

[image: punch back]

[Backbone.js has the exact same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15824887/backbone-js-avoid-viewmodelview-double-conversion).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You ask,

> Is there any way to avoid updates on the currently modified element?

In general, not really. This is actually a *feature* of React: your UI is guaranteed to always be in sync with your underlying data! Of course, by overriding `shouldComponentUpdate` and doing some manual work you can prevent the fields from changing, but it's intentional that the path of least resistance leads you to an always-accurate UI.

It sounds like you want to be able to show either an exact °C temperature or an exact °F temperature, so the best approach here seems to be to *store* that as well. Otherwise, you're feigning more precision than you actually have. I've modified your code so that it operates in one of two modes: Celsius mode or Fahrenheit mode:

```
var TempConverter = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {type: "c", val: 0};
    },
    render: function() {
        var c, f;
        if (this.state.type === "c") {
            c = this.state.val;
            f = c2f(c);
        } else {
            f = this.state.val;
            c = f2c(f);
        }
```

Tracking the value this way allows you to store and display the exact temperature the user entered and be confident that you're not losing any precision.

Live demo here: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/spicyj/3g4bR/)

(You could also round the temperature before displaying, of course, but your response to your Backbone.js question indicates that's not your preferred solution.)